# Is there any way to have my transactions show up in my timezone in the Recurly transactions table?

Tags: timezone, recurly

On https://mysubdomain.recurly.com/transactions the transaction date uses UTC timezone instead of the timezone selected on **Home -> Site Settings -> Company Location -> Timezone** https://mysubdomain.recurly.com/configuration/edit .  Is there any way to have my transactions show up in my timezone on that page?

**Expected:** Mar 9, 2016 11:14 AM EST

**Actual:** Mar 9, 2016 4:14 PM UTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on your name in the top right corner of your Recurly UI. You can then change your profile timezone settings (eg https://app.recurly.com/go/profile/edit)

Comment: Oh Awesome!.  From a user experience standpoint that was hard to find.  Might be better located on the left navigation.